# Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'char *' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: nsstring, char, ios8, xcode6, nsmutablestring

For the following line of code I am getting the error below:

```
for (UILabel *label in labels) {
    label.text = label.tag - 100 > someMutableString.length ? "" : "*";
}
```

The error states:

> Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'char *' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC

My variable "someMutableString" is of type NSMutableString.

How do I fix in my particular case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that your string literals are `""` and `"*"` which are both C-style strings (`const char*`). So the type of the right hand side of the assignment is also `const char*`. You are assigning to the `text` property of a `UILabel`, which takes an `NSString`.

Use `@""` and `@"*"` instead.

Comment: that was it.  Hopefully it helps somebody else too as when I search I didn't find this type of example associated with that error.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *text = "a"

NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",text];
```

**Cheers :)**